# using html tag in SVG for IE9,10,11

Tags: html, svg, jquery-svg

I need help regarding using the foreignObject tag in svg. 
I have the following code which I am trying it to make it work in IE11.

```
             <svg>
                <switch>
                  <foreignObject x="43" y="184" width="220px" height="26px"
 requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
                    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <input id="lpnz_dup" class="diagTextArea" style=" width:216px;" placeholder=" eg: trust"/>
                    </body>
                  </foreignObject>
                </switch>
            </svg>
```

Here is the link to a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/2FLru/1/. works well in chrome and firefox. Doesnot work in IE11, havent checked whether it works on IE10,9.

I searched for a solution, but unsuccessful. Had anyone faced the same problem and know a workaround

Comment: `<foreignObject>` is not supported in IE9, 10 or 11. You'd need to do things the other way round i.e. have an html file and embed SVG in it.

Comment: Yes I know about the foreignObject hence I was looking if someone has figured a work around for this problem in IE.

Comment: I provided the only possible workaround i.e. have an html document and embed the SVG in it either inline or using object image or iframe tags or CSS things like background-images. Those are the only ways in IE to mix html and SVG currently.